# Dynamically adding to a image search in html

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to add profile pictures for an NHL stats website I am currently working on and I wondering how to dynamically change the link address for an image search. here is my script to append it to the body at this time. I do not know how to join the link plus the player id ({{p1_ID}}) and add the .png at the end

```
<script>
var imgPath = 'https://nhl.bamcontent.com/images/headshots/current/168x168/';
var image = document.createElement('img');
var player_ID = document.getElementById("p1");
image.src =  imgPath + player_ID + '.png';
document.body.appendChild(image);
</script>
<p id="p1">{{p1_ID}}</p>
```

Comment: `imgPath` is a string, '.png' is a string, but `player_ID` is a DOM [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element) object, not a string. You don't show what the expanded content of the element with id "p1" is, but you probably want the `innerText` or part of the innerText of that.

Comment: is there any way to use the angular expression {{p1_ID}} that just contains an 8 digit numerical player ID into a string without using it from a predetermined element with a id attribute such in a paragraph. sorry I'm brand new to JS and HTML

Comment: Yes, there is a way — see cstrat's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you can't implement the following (or something along these lines):

```
<p id="p1">{{p1_ID}}</p>
<img src="https://nhl.bamcontent.com/images/headshots/current/168x168/{{p1_ID}}.png" />
```

I don't know what templating engine you're using so that may not work, but if you provide more detail it would help.

Comment: Joey mentions Angular in a comment. There _may_ be a reason why the img needs to be appended later, but there's no indication in the question why that would be necessary -- I think you could phrase this more as an answer, less as a question "is there any reason…?"  and it would be fine as a potential answer.

Comment: I am using Jinja2 provided in Flask as the data is pulled from APIs in a python script that outputs angular expressions to HTML. I've tried adding the {{p1_ID}} at the end of the link but when I inspect element to see if it even pull any data there was nothing